# Elastic Search Get index API to get indices older than 30 days

Tags: elasticsearch

we are using elastic-search 5 and i need to delete indices older than 30 days through API.Can any can help me out for this?

Comment: you need to create indices older than 30 days or indices inactive for more than 30 days?

Answer (score 0):

You can use curator to do that.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.x/delete_indices.html

```
curator --host <hostname> delete indices --older-than 30
```

Comment: hostname means system hostname where elastic search is running right?

Comment: ERROR     Parameters --older-than and --newer-than require the --time-unit parameter